# Конвертация строки латинской раскладки на рус. язык

Tags: php

Друзья, подскажите, есть ли готовая функция на php либо как создать свою. Задача состоит в том, что пользователь в инпуте может забыть переключить язык и написать слово:

```
<jkufhbz
```

Что на русском `Болгария`.

Как сделать конвертацию? Интересует решение на PHP

Comment: `$map = ['q' => 'й', 'w' => 'ц', ....] ` Вам бы во первых сначала убедиться, что он действительно забыл переключить, а потом убедиться, что забыл он переключить английский, а не какой нибудь финский или шведский, и сделал он это в раскладке qwerty-йцукен а не какой-нибудь еще, машинописной к примеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ideone.com/50a3UP

```
<?php

$dict = array(
  "`"=>"ё","-"=>"-","="=>"=","\\"=>"\\","q"=>"й","w"=>"ц","e"=>"у","r"=>"к","t"=>"е","y"=>"н","u"=>"г","i"=>"ш","o"=>"щ","p"=>"з","["=>"х","]"=>"ъ","a"=>"ф","s"=>"ы","d"=>"в","f"=>"а","g"=>"п","h"=>"р","j"=>"о","k"=>"л","l"=>"д",";"=>"ж","'"=>"э","z"=>"я","x"=>"ч","c"=>"с","v"=>"м","b"=>"и","n"=>"т","m"=>"ь",","=>"б","."=>"ю","/"=>".","~"=>"Ё","!"=>"!","@"=>"\"","#"=>"№","$"=>";","%"=>"%","^"=>":","&"=>"?","*"=>"*","("=>"(",")"=>")","_"=>"_","+"=>"+","|"=>"/","Q"=>"Й","W"=>"Ц","E"=>"У","R"=>"К","T"=>"Е","Y"=>"Н","U"=>"Г","I"=>"Ш","O"=>"Щ","P"=>"З","{"=>"Х","}"=>"Ъ","A"=>"Ф","S"=>"Ы","D"=>"В","F"=>"А","G"=>"П","H"=>"Р","J"=>"О","K"=>"Л","L"=>"Д",":"=>"Ж","\""=>"Э","Z"=>"Я","X"=>"Ч","C"=>"С","V"=>"М","B"=>"И","N"=>"Т","M"=>"Ь","<"=>"Б",">"=>"Ю","?"=>",",
  "ё"=>"`","-"=>"-","="=>"=","\\"=>"\\","й"=>"q","ц"=>"w","у"=>"e","к"=>"r","е"=>"t","н"=>"y","г"=>"u","ш"=>"i","щ"=>"o","з"=>"p","х"=>"[","ъ"=>"]","ф"=>"a","ы"=>"s","в"=>"d","а"=>"f","п"=>"g","р"=>"h","о"=>"j","л"=>"k","д"=>"l","ж"=>";","э"=>"'","я"=>"z","ч"=>"x","с"=>"c","м"=>"v","и"=>"b","т"=>"n","ь"=>"m","б"=>",","ю"=>".","."=>"/","Ё"=>"~","!"=>"!","\""=>"@","№"=>"#",";"=>"$","%"=>"%",":"=>"^","?"=>"&","*"=>"*","("=>"(",")"=>")","_"=>"_","+"=>"+","/"=>"|","Й"=>"Q","Ц"=>"W","У"=>"E","К"=>"R","Е"=>"T","Н"=>"Y","Г"=>"U","Ш"=>"I","Щ"=>"O","З"=>"P","Х"=>"{","Ъ"=>"}","Ф"=>"A","Ы"=>"S","В"=>"D","А"=>"F","П"=>"G","Р"=>"H","О"=>"J","Л"=>"K","Д"=>"L","Ж"=>":","Э"=>"\"","Я"=>"Z","Ч"=>"X","С"=>"C","М"=>"V","И"=>"B","Т"=>"N","Ь"=>"M","Б"=>"<","Ю"=>">",","=>"?"
);

function invertLayout($str) {
  return preg_replace_callback('~.~u', function ($match) {
    global $dict;
    return isset($dict[$match[0]]) ? $dict[$match[0]] : $match[0];
  }, $str);
}

echo invertLayout('<jkufhbz Болгария');
```

Получено так:

```js
var [[...e],[...r]] = document.querySelector('textarea').value.split("\n").filter(x=>x)

var code = `$dict = array(
  ${e.map((c,i)=>`${JSON.stringify(c)}=>${JSON.stringify(r[i])}`).join(",")},
  ${r.map((c,i)=>`${JSON.stringify(c)}=>${JSON.stringify(e[i])}`).join(",")}
);

function invertLayout($str) {
  return preg_replace_callback('~.~u', function ($match) {
    global $dict;
    return isset($dict[$match[0]]) ? $dict[$match[0]] : $match[0];
  }, $str);
}`

console.log(code)
```

```css
textarea {width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; height:4em; white-space:pre; resize:none;}
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100vh;}
```

```html
<textarea readonly>
`-=\qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*()_+|QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?
ё-=\йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.Ё!"№;%:?*()_+/ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,
</textarea>
```